# Unable to put a category picture in prestashop

Tags: ftp, prestashop, laravel-blade, prestashop-1.5

I'm trying to put an image as "category image". The one you'll see when you go to [this](http://dev.ouistipix.com/tirages-photo--7) page.

[image]

Unfortunatly I dont get how to do it via the admin side and when I try to change it directly using her position in the FTP server I come up with this error :

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /themes/ouistipix/img/category/23.jpg on this server.
```

Strangely it works for other category.. Do you know why and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

To change category image from Pretashop backoffice, go to `Catalog -> Categories`,(for 1.6) on right side of category name click on arrow (next to View button) and choose `Edit`, on edit page you will see possibilities for delete current image or upload new.

Permissions issue:

- for allowing Prestashop set images for products/categories etc. img/ folder must be writable for web server recursively (including subfolders).
- to upload/delete through FTP, folder must be writable for FTP user.

Just check what permissions and owner you have for folder and this specific file.

Comment: Exactyl it I've manage to resolve this by changing the permissions in the acces right to the file to tue classic -rw--r-r-- (Or something like this).
Thank you for the answer anyway